# Parameter space of twisted cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

In section 12.9 from *Algebraic Geometry - A First Course* by Joe Harris, the author computes the dimension of the parameter space of twisted cubics, even if he doesn't give a construction of this space. How does this spaces look like? Is the construction too complicated for the level he assumes?

This computation was asked at some exam where also wasn't assumed any explicit construction. Though, at that exam it was also asked if this space is irreducible. How can one see that without knowing how the space looks like?

Comment: Piene, R., & Schlessinger, M. (1985). _On_ _the_ _Hilbert_ _Scheme_ _Compactification_ _of_ _the_ _Space_ _of_ _Twisted_ _Cubics_. American Journal of Mathematics, 107(4), 761-774. [doi:10.2307/2374355](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2374355)

Comment: If you're interested, [here](https://github.com/Macaulay2/M2/blob/master/M2/Macaulay2/packages/Schubert2/Stromme/letter_to_collino.txt)'s how to compute in the enumerative geometry package [schubert](https://github.com/jmokland/schubert) for maple with the space H3.

Comment: Thank you for the sources!